# Change control in Trust Centre

Tags: vbscript, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010, outlook-2007

I am developing a basic VBScript to send an E-mail using my script. 
I have an application that sends email out. I have to click on the allow/deny for each email. I want to be able to turn this off so I can avoid this message.

The requirement is to enable radio button "Never warn me about any suspicious activity (not recommended)"  present in "Trust Centre" option during every time when I send a email using my script.

My basic question is does it possible to do this using VB script. I googled and tried sample examples but could not open even Trust Centre option. I am sure missing out something. Hence  I got a basic question that whether it is really possible to use VBScript.

I tried changing registry setting and it works fine. But it is not required as per my project requirement.

Comment: Don't send via Outlook.

Comment: Outlook cannot be ignored as per project requirement

Comment: Your only other option is to change the trust center settings. Can't have the cake and eat it too.